# Klondike Solitaire - what to do if 1 or 2 cards are left in the stock?

Tags: solitaire, klondike-solitaire

As far as I understand it, in standard Klondike solitaire, you deal 3 cards at a time from the stock to the waste.  What if only 1 or 2 cards are left in the stock?

Comment: Pretty sure you just deal the last 1/2 cards as normal and that is how it is handled on the computer.

Comment: That just means you have lost the game.

Comment: @Chenmunka If you only manage to play 1 or 2 cards from the deck on the first cycle of the draw deck you would get in this situation and that does not mean you lose.

Answer (score 3):

you deal out the cards up to three. If there are less than three you just deal out those cards. Use what you can. And then put them in the discard pile and start over.

If those are the only cards you have left including the rest of the discard pile then you might be in a lose scenario.